# How to slice a multi-dimensional array with another multi-dimensional array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, slice

I have, say, a 2D-array:

```
x = np.array([[4, 5, 6],
              [7, 8, 9]])
```

and another one with indexes:

```
a = np.array([[0, 1],
              [1, 2]])
```

How do I slice each row of *x* using the indexes in each respective row in *a* without using a loop in order to obtain:

```
[[4, 5]
 [8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[4, 5, 6],
              [7, 8, 9]])
a = np.array([[0, 1],
              [1, 2]])
print(np.take_along_axis(x,a,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.take_along_axis`

```
np.take_along_axis(x,a,1)
# array([[4, 5],
#        [8, 9]])
```

or manually add the first coordinate (broadcasting applies)

```
x[np.c_[:2],a]
# array([[4, 5],
#        [8, 9]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is technically a loop, but you can do it in one line with a list comprehension.

```
print(np.array([x[i][a[i]] for i in range(0, x.shape[0])]))
```